# Where are _help, _label and other attributes defined in playframework?

Tags: scala, playframework

In Play/Scala, the helper package has several methods to create HTML template. We can provide various attributes while creating the template. For example, in following, I have used _help to provide helpful description about the element. I noticed from other examples that there are other attributes like _label etc. Where can I get list of all such attributes specific to a method in the helper package (inputText, inputDate, inputPassword etc.) either in source code or documentation?

```
@helper.inputText(form("name"), '_help->"Enter name")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are field constructor parameters (args parameter of [views.html.helper.FieldElements](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.FieldElements) to be precise). From the [docs](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms#showing-forms-in-a-view-template):

> **Note**: All extra parameters will be added to the generated Html, unless they start with the _ character. Arguments starting with _ are reserved for field constructor arguments.

Play's default field constructor has six additional options defined that will be handled. Again from the [docs](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCustomFieldConstructors#custom-field-constructors):

- `'_label`
- `'_id`
- `'_help`
- `'_showConstraints`
- `'_error`
- `'_showErrors`

You can write your own field constructor that handles additional options. Everything that is preceeded with `_` will eventually be passed into the field constructor.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is correct. Could you also tell me (or point to documentation) about how to create own/additional options?

Comment: See [Writing your own field constructor](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCustomFieldConstructors#writing-your-own-field-constructor). You can pass any argument you like. E.g. `'_some -> "thing"`. In your custom field constructor those "options" will be available in a `Map` under `elements.args`. Feel free to ask a new question if you're struggling :)

Comment: I was able to use it as follows in my field constructor. Does this seem light the right way to use it (my argument's name is '_mycolor' `<div class="@if(elements.hasErrors) {error}" style="color:@elements.args('_mycolor)">`